# Liquibase changeset changeLogPropertyDefined is not working

Tags: liquibase

In liquibase  I want to execute a particular change set based on the 'context' property value.
In this case I have passed  -Dcontext=local (I've checked this values is getting picked properly) through command line and  tried to check that property within my changeset by using changeLogPropertyDefined. But It's not working..
Please find below my changeset

```
<changeSet  id="1"  author="dm">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onSqlOutput="TEST">
            <changeLogPropertyDefined  property="context" value="local"/>
        </preConditions>
        <createTable tableName="accountold">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
        <column name="version" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

Comment: what command are you using while running liquibase update?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the "link" to the property in the top of your changeset file to reference value is passed from jvm args:

```
<property name="context" value="${context}"/>
```

Then you could use your property in precondition and anywhere you want in this changeset.

P.S. Maybe it's will be better to give different name for jvm arg and lb property to avoid ambiguity of interpretation.

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working---

<property name="env" value="${context}" />



<changeSet  id="1"  author="dm">
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onSqlOutput="TEST">
        <changeLogPropertyDefined  property="env" value="local"/>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="accounttest">
    <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"/>
    </column>
    <column name="version" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>